# Pay Plugin (Google Pay) + flutter_stripe Integration

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, google-pay

I'm trying to integrate the Flutter [pay plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) with the [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_stripe/latest/) package.

I need help understanding how to process the `PaymentToken` that the Google Pay API returns. I've completed integrating the pay plugin with my flutter app.

How am I now supposed to process the token that the plugin returns using the `flutter_stripe` package?

Comment: can you clarify exactly what guide you're following or share some code? As far as I know you don't get a payment token, it's all abstracted and you just use the PaymentSheet and it will present the Google Pay option and process payment with it for you, you don't have to use the Google Pay API yourself and tokenize with it or anything.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/overview#how-it-works). The section gives an idea of how things work. I need help with step 3 and 4. @karllekko

Comment: The flutter plugin I'm using for Google Pay is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/pay).

Comment: Hello, I am getting error "Invalid token ID: tok_xx" when i send the token to stripe. did you manage to integrate google pay with stripe?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official Stripe Flutter plugin instead(https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe).

But if you're doing it the way you linked then you need to set up the gateway tokenization to use your Stripe API keys for example :  https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#tokenization
[image]

When you're finished the process it then gives you a tok_xxx Stripe token at the end(it's in the JSON of the PaymentData https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentData ) which can be used by their API — you call https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card  to convert the Token to a PaymentMethod [ 0 ] and then confirm a PaymentIntent with it.

It's pretty complex and undocumented so I'd suggest just using an official Stripe integration.

[0] -
e.g. if your backend is in Node and `tok_xxx` is the token you got from Google Pay and have sent to your backend then you can create a PaymentMethod with it and then use with a PaymentIntent (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-payment_method) :

```
let pm = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
    type:"card",
    card: {
        token:"tok_xxxx"
    }
})
```